# quickly ignores subfolder

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, packaging

I have a problem with packaging quickly. I have a project foo:

> foo/
>   foo/bar/
>   foo_lib/
>   data/

When I run
`quickly package --extras && file-roller ../*deb`
I always miss `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/foo/foo/bar` in the deb-file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I kind of solved it by now.

I've edited the setup.py in the project folder. I extended the setup on the last lines:

```
DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(  
name='foo'  
version='0.1-public1',  
license='GPL-3',  
author='Alex',  
author_email='alex@foo.bar',  
description='This is foo',  
long_description='with a lot of bar',  
url='www.foo.bar',  
cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory}  
)
```

by appending three parameters:

```
DistUtilsExtra.auto.setup(  
name='foo'  
version='0.1-public1',  
license='GPL-3',  
author='Alex',  
author_email='alex@foo.bar',  
description='This is foo',  
long_description='with a lot of bar',  
url='www.foo.bar',  
cmdclass={'install': InstallAndUpdateDataDirectory},  
packages=['foo', 'foo_lib', 'foo/bar'],  
package_data={  
    'foo': ['*.py'],  
    'foo_lib': ['*.py'],  
    'foo/bar': ['*.py']  
    },  
package_dir={  
    'foo': 'foo',  
    'foo_lib': 'foo_lib',  
    'foo/bar': 'foo/bar'  
    },  
)
```

I'm not sure, if this is the way it should be solved, but at least it works for me :-)

I hope I can help someone else out there, too...